# How do I break a loop in this situation?

Tags: python, function, loops, break

I just wrote a program that will give the number of students that passed & failed, marks, letter grades, and average class grades. I think the code doesn't work because it only gets through the collect() and not calculate() and passer(). Does anyone know how I can connect the three functions?

Have a great day guys!! :)

**My code:**

```
list_grade = []
list_score = []
def collect():
    while True:
        score = input("Student's score: ")
        if score == "done":
        average(list_grade)
            break
        else:
            list_grade.append(float(score))
def average(list_grade):
    average_grade = sum(list_grade)/len(list_grade)
    calculate()
def calculate():
    for element in list_grade:
        if element >= 80:
            list_score.append("A")
        elif element >= 70:
            list_score.append("B")
        elif element >= 60:
            list_score.append("C")
        elif element >= 50:
            list_score.append("D")
        elif element >= 40:
            list_score.append("F")
        passer()
def passer():
    s_fail = 0
    s_pass = 0    
    for element in list_score:
        if element == 'F':
            s_fail += 1
        else:
            s_pass += 1
collect()

print ("Number of students that failed: " + s_fail)
print ("Number of students that passed: " + s_pass)
print ("Marks: " + list_grade)
print ("Letter grades: " + list_score)
print ("Average class grade: " + average_grade)
```

Comment: there is no way that it goes appended to the list in the `collect()` function. Try to edit your question, becasue python would throw an error if it had to append the list with the converted `string` to `float`

Comment: What makes you think that: ‘ "done" gets into the list.grade’ ?

Comment: @quamrana I just looked into pythonTutor and that told me whenever I typed in "done" it throws a ValueError because it "couldn't convert string to float: 'done'".

Comment: btw I think that you should move: ‘average(list_grade)’ up to just before ‘break’, otherwise the scores get calculated too many times.

Comment: Ok, if you get ValueError you should update the question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw True.. I'll tryta find something else that messes everything up

Comment: @quamrana right.. I'll do that right now. Thanks for letting me know about taking the average(list_grade) up! :)

Comment: @JustinKim if you find that, please mention me and I will fix code for you

Comment: btw in your current code print won't work since you don't have access to the local variables `s_fail, s_pass, average_grade `?

Comment: @JustinKim I have fixed your code. It is working now

Comment: @DarrylG true.. just noticed that. Thanks for the help!! :)

Comment: @JustinKim--in your accepted answer use of globals is generally frowned upon except for certain situations (this is not one of them).  It's better for software encapsulation and user understanding, in this case, to return s_fail, s_pass, average_grade to the caller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed your code. the problem was that you wanted to print out the values from the `passer()` and the `average()` function. In order to do that outside of a function, you have to use the `global` keyword. It will make these variables available in the whole file.

```
def passer():
    global s_fail, s_pass
    s_fail = 0
    s_pass = 0
    for element in list_score:
        if element == 'F':
            s_fail += 1
        else:
            s_pass += 1
```

```
def average(list_grade):
    global average_grade
    average_grade = sum(list_grade)/len(list_grade)
    calculate()
```

The next issue is with the `print()` functions. You can not print the `int` type values. You have to change your code to the following

```
print ("Number of students that failed: " + str(s_fail))
print ("Number of students that passed: " + str(s_pass))
print ("Marks: " + str(list_grade))
print ("Letter grades: " + str(list_score))
print ("Average class grade: " + str(average_grade))
```

However, you could print the `int` type values but you would have to use the `f string` and the code would look

```
print (f"Number of students that failed: {s_fail}")
print (f"Number of students that passed: {s_pass}")
print (f"Marks: {list_grade}")
print (f"Letter grades: {list_score}")
print (f"Average class grade: {average_grade}")
```

Comment: Ohh, I didn't know about the global keyword at all, and that there were some issues in my code in the print section. Thank you so much for the help!! :)